# Mobile menu doesn't close in Joomla Bootstrap custom template

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I built a Joomla template to redesign my company's website's front end. Everything works and it looks nicely. My only problem now is the mobile menu. It opens up when you click the menu button, but it doesn't close. The only way to get rid of it is to select a link or refresh the page.

I know the issue is Joomla uses a custom version of `Bootstrap.js` but if I include my own standard `Bootstrap.js` file then everything stops working because conflicting calls to JavaScript happen.

Does anything know of a solution to this?

The website is [www.DriveAndShine.com](http://www.driveandshine.com/)

Comment: @isherwood I know what those errors were about. It was just some JS that i was testing. I removed it.

Comment: @Lodder the JS files being loaded at the top are loaded by Joomla, I didn't place them there.

Comment: Use the code that @Onur has shon you in his answer and put it in the `<head>`. Don't forget to wrap it in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ..... });`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navbar" style="height: 456px; background-color: rgb(17, 3, 140);" 
  class="navbar-collapse collapse **in**">
```

class in looks like not removed when you reclicked the menu you can use jQuery hasClass method for #navbar ( please include jquery before running the code )

```
if($('#navbar').hasClass('in')) {
   $('#navbar').removeClass('in');
} else {
   $('#navbar').addClass('in');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I see that. For some reason it isn't loaded JQuery so I'll have to come up with pure JavaScript to add that in.

Comment: @AbrahamA. - jQuery **is** being loaded....from `/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js`. I can see it in the inspector. You're most likely not adding the code to the correct place and wrapping it in Dom read

Comment: Ok, I added it to the top but now it is the opposite problem. It loads the menu open and closes once, but it won't open again.

Comment: @Lodder It's now seeing the Jquery but the problem is backwards now.

Comment: I changed up the code to be a call when the button is pressed, but now it doesn't do anything. 

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#menuButton').click(function(){
   if($('#navbar').hasClass('in')) {
     $('#navbar').removeClass('in');
   } else {
     $('#navbar').addClass('in');
   }
  });
 });